# ¿Como reproducir videos con la libreria IO de Python?

Tags: python, django, python-2.x

Quisiera reproducir un vídeo que obtengo desde un servidor ftp, en este momento el archivo se está guardando en el servidor pero no quiero que se guarde sino que se reproduzca de manera inmediata.

Me comentaron que con la librería io se puede hacer pero quisiera saber como.

Código de mi view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def MostrarVideo(request):  

    nombre = request.POST['nombre']
    apellido = request.POST['apellido']
    filename = nombre + apellido + ".mp4"

    import ftplib

    ftp = ftplib.FTP('dirser', 'user', 'pass')
    ftp.dir()

    try:
       # Aquí es donde abro el archivo en mi servidor para que se guarde
        with open("videos/"+filename, 'wb') as f:
        # Aquí escribo los datos desde el servidor ftp hasta la carpeta videos en el Django
            ftp.retrbinary("RETR "+filename ,f.write)
    except Exception as e:
        print "Error " + str(e)
        return HttpResponse(0)
    print("Enviando")
    return HttpResponse(filename)
```

Comment: Que python estas usando? no he podido responderte bien por no haber probado la respuesta, en cuanto pueda te respondo bien

Comment: Python 2.7.13 ... Listo de verdad me ayudarias mucho, de ante mano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, si quieres reproducir tu vídeo, esa, es otra pregunta, que no tiene mucho que ver con django o python. Además de que hay muchas formas de hacerlo. Básicamente lo quieres tu es hacer una especie de proxy, en la cual tu servidor hace la petición a otro servidor ftp para conseguir los archivos. En este caso un mp3. Yo lo devolveré como 'attachment' o archivo adjunto. Pero igual tu podrías hacer un stream o no sé.

```
import io
import ftplib
from django.http import HttpResponseServerError


@csrf_exempt
def mostrar_video(request):
    nombre = request.POST.get('nombre', '').strip()
    apellido = request.POST.get('apellido', '').strip()

    filename = '{}{}.mp4'.format(nombre, apellido)

    ftp = ftplib.FTP('dirser', 'user', 'pass')
    ftp.dir()
    response = HttpResponse()

    try:
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR {}'format(filename), buffer.write)
        response.content_type = 'video/mp4'
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(filename)
        response.write(buffer.getvalue())
        buffer.close()
    except Exception as error:
        response = HttpResponseServerError(error.__str__())
    return response
```

Comentame como te va con este fragmento de código, dado que no he podido probar.

Comment: Me retorna un error 550 que significa **Requested action not taken. File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).**

Comment: En que momento te sale ese error???

Comment: En esta linea:
**ftp.retrbinary("RETR {}".format(filename), buffer.write)**

Comment: Estoy leyendo un poco acerca de `ftplib` y al parecer ese es un error del lado del servidor, por lo que el servidor de ftp te está negando el acceso al archivo, estas seguro que tienes permisos para acceder a ese archivo?

Comment: En esta linea le doy la dirección de donde se encuentra el servidor y también el usuario y la contraseña que me dan acceso.
   **ftp = ftplib.FTP('dirser', 'user', 'pass')**

Comment: intenta sacar el mismo archivo que estas intentando, desde una shell, y guardarlo en tu pc, a ver si te da permisos.

Comment: Acabo de guardarlo en mi computador en la carpeta static del servidor y si me da permisos lo hago de esta manera:   
**with open("static/videos/"+filename, 'wb') as f:
 ftp.retrbinary("RETR "+filename ,f.write)**

Comment: Debo revisar y hacer pruebas a ver como lo ayudo. Que bueno que sea colega de la arenosa

Comment: Te lo agradecería mucho, en este momento estoy creando el archivo temporal en el servidor para posteriormente eliminarlo pero estoy seguro que con el buffer para reproducir el video sería mucho más sencilla la ejecución. Gracias, espero seamos más pronto, Saludos!